# Calculate the time spent in a room on G-sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I am trying to make a calculation on how to automatically see how long Paul, Jack and John spent in the room as shown on the enclosed pic. I cannot figure out if I should have an IF formula added with a VLOOK, but I am not sure and need your expertise. Please help

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a properly-formatted table showing your spreadsheet data, instead of an image - this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important. Aside from that, please show your work: what you've tried, issues, errors, expected vs actual output, etc.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous - do you mean time each person spent 'in' individually (2, 4 and 1 hour I think) or how long the room was occupied (5 hours) or what their times add up to (7 hours) ?

Comment: I mean for example how long did Jack spend in the room from his Check in time until his check out time

Comment: @DavidMakogon Here is the table
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x3HrfTDndaLPCxBZeons_xkL6hWM9E72b_RYT0oYeV0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: As the data keep on coming through a G-form, I'd like to make it automatic to see how long each individual has spent in the room.

Comment: @Jerome - I didn't mean "share a link" - I meant, create a nice, readable, formatted table (in markdown), in your question. Nobody should have to visit an external site to understand your question. And there are issues with sharing images of text.

Answer (score 0):

use in D2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="",,IF(ISODD(
 COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(C2:C), "<="&ROW(C2:C))), "IN", "OUT")))
```

use in E2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(TEXT(VLOOKUP(A2:A&C2:C&D2:D, 
 {FILTER(A2:A&C2:C&D2:D, D2:D="OUT"), 
 QUERY(FILTER(B2:B, ISEVEN(COUNTIFS(A2:A&C2:C, A2:A&C2:C, ROW(C2:C), 
 "<="&ROW(C2:C)))), "where Col1 is not null")-
 QUERY(FILTER(B2:B,  ISODD(COUNTIFS(A2:A&C2:C, A2:A&C2:C, ROW(C2:C), 
 "<="&ROW(C2:C)))), "where Col1 is not null")}, 2, 0), "[h]:mm:ss")))
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine if the person is only coming once in the room, however, if the person is visiting multiple times, it shows the previous duration

Comment: @Jerome yes. given the small sample, you provided and almost no intel on how it should behave in multiple scenarios, this is the best I could offer you.